# How much Oxygen can the Human body carry?

Tags: human-biology, biochemistry

Basically - the title: How much Oxygen does a human body carry at a single point?

---

What have I tried: A friend of mine has done some calculations and came up with the following numbers. Neither of us are biologists or have higher degrees in biology. His calculation went something like:

- Our body absorbs about 0.033g of Oxygen when we inhale ([source](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-mass-of-oxygen-inhaled-during-one-normal-and-full-breath/answer/Nissim-Raj-Angdembay)).

  - That's about 0.00103 moles of oxygen.
  - Through ATP reaction that's about 0.00515 moles of ATP
- We have 270 millions of hemoglobin per red blood cell, and roughly 25 trillions of blood cells in our body ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_blood_cell#Human)), and each Hemoglobin molecule "carries" up to 4 oxygen molecules.
- Thus, in total, our body's hemoglobin can carry about (2.5 * 10^13) * (270 * 10^6) * 4 = 1.437 grams of oxygen

**How far is the 1.437g number have?**

Related (but not the same question) question I found here: [How much energy we get from oxygen?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/73893/how-much-energy-we-get-from-oxygen).

Note: this is specifically about oxygen we use in our respiratory system - and not the oxygen in the water :]

Comment: What do you mean by "carry"?  My first thought is a strong person carrying a large Dewar vessel full of liquid oxygen :-)

Comment: @jamesqf as in - "our blood carries oxygen through our body - how much oxygen does it carry at a given point?"

Comment: Don't forget that all of the water and many of the organic compounds in our bodies also contain oxygen...

Comment: Presumably you have your own reasons for asking this question, but you should not be surprised if nobody else is interested unless you explain why it is of interest.

Comment: @David I am interested in this because it is interesting and because we are trying to practice doing these calculations as non-biologists :]

Comment: Fair enough. This sort of thing is a minority interest, but you may find a physiologist on the list who does these types of calculations.

Comment: @David that is fair, this site and community does not owe me an answer and I am not entitled to anyone's help. I am just hoping that someone who also finds this interesting but has more technical competence than me takes a look and does the calculations better than me.